# Array into ranges of consecutive numbers

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to make a Ruby function that converts an array of unique numbers into ranges of consecutive numbers.

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9] => [(1..3), (5..6), (8..9)]
```

It doesn't seem too hard, but I want to know if there's better way.

Comment: Better way than what? You haven't posted your solution

Comment: When you ask for code on SO, you are expected to provide what you've already tried in search of an answer. We need to know you're putting in some effort, not just trolling for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [solution](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/convert-ruby-array-ranges) to the same question you're asking. The linked code does a bit more work than you require (the numbers don't need to be sorted, or consecutive), but it'll do the trick. Or, you could use this code, suggested by @NewAlexandria :

```
class Array
   def to_ranges
      compact.sort.uniq.inject([]) do |r,x|
         r.empty? || r.last.last.succ != x ? r << (x..x) : r[0..-2] << (r.last.first..x)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Hmm... actually, I think that NewAlexandria simply copied the code from your link into the question... so, technically, it's the code *you* suggested...

Answer (score 4):

How is this using [**`Enumerable#slice_before`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before)?

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
prev = ar[0]
p ar.slice_before { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev2 + 1 != e
}.map{|a| a[0]..a[-1]} 
# >> [1..3, 5..6, 8..9]

ar = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6,7, 8, 9,11]
prev = ar[0]
p ar.slice_before { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev2 + 1 != e
}.map{|a| a[0]..a[-1]} 
# >> [1..3, 5..9, 11..11]
```

Comment: I like this solution very much.

Comment: It seems to have made its way into the documentation:  https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/slice_before

Answer (score 3):

This is something I wrote a while back when dealing with IP address ranges:

```
class Array
  # [1,2,4,5,6,7,9,13].to_ranges       # => [1..2, 4..7, 9..9, 13..13]
  # [1,2,4,5,6,7,9,13].to_ranges(true) # => [1..2, 4..7, 9, 13]
  def to_ranges(non_ranges_ok=false)
    self.sort.each_with_index.chunk { |x, i| x - i }.map { |diff, pairs|
      if (non_ranges_ok)
        pairs.first[0] == pairs.last[0] ? pairs.first[0] : pairs.first[0] .. pairs.last[0]
      else
        pairs.first[0] .. pairs.last[0]
      end
    }
  end
end

if ($0 == __FILE__)
  require 'awesome_print'

  ary = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 12]
  puts ary.join(', ')
  ap ary.to_ranges

  ary = [1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 11, 12, 10]
  puts ary.join(', ')
  ap ary.to_ranges

end
```

Pass `true` to `to_ranges` and it will not convert individual elements into one-element ranges.

Comment: Nice method! Though I'm curious when you *wouldn't* want the parameter to be true.

Comment: I had times I needed to shrink an array into ranges and values. This isn't useful for just integers; Like I said in the code, I used it to turn IP numbers into network ranges and individual IPs. Other times I just wanted ranges.

Comment: Worked like charm. I love you, thanks for saving me several minutes of algorigthming